# Why "this.props.match.params.authorName" gives undefined/empty value in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get the `authorName` which is a query parameter sent, so I can get that value and search `MongoDB`

I am calling `FilterBooks` component through another component called `Authors`

This is my `Authors.jsx`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import FilterBooks from './filter-books'

const SelectOption = (props) => (
        <option value={props.author.firstName}>{`${props.author.firstName} ${props.author.lastName}`}</option>
)

export default class Authors extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            authorArray: [],
            authorName: ''
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/books/authors')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                authorArray: res.data
            });
        });
    }


    getAuthors(){
        return this.state.authorArray.map((currentAuthor, id) => {
            return <SelectOption author={currentAuthor} key={id} />
        });
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            authorName: e.target.value
        });

    }


    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
            <div className="container">
                <h3>Authors List</h3>

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <select
                    value={this.state.authorName}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    className="form-control" id="authors" name="authors">
                        <option>- Author List -</option>
                        {this.getAuthors()}
                    </select>
                    <br />
                    {/* <Link  to={`/authors/${this.state.authorName}`} className="btn btn-success" >View Books</Link> */}
                    <Link  to={`/authors/${this.state.authorName}`} className="btn btn-success" >View Books</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            {/* <Route path={`/authors/${this.state.authorName}`} exact Component={FilterBooks} /> */}
            <Route path={`/authors/${this.state.authorName}`} component={FilterBooks}/>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

This is my `FilterBook.jsx`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

export default class FilterBooks extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/books/authors/" + this.props.match.params.authorName)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello Books</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is my `server.js` which handles backend. Here I have removed other end-points so this code will look short and sweet and clear.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const BookDB = require('./book-dbmodel');
const AuthorDB = require('./author-dbmodel');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/books', router);

//connect to books database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/books', {useNewUrlParser: true});

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB via port 27017");
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Listening to port 4000');
});


//get books by author name http://localhost:4000/books/authors/authorName
router.route('/authors/:authorName').get((req, res) => {
    let authorName = req.params.authorName;
    BookDB.find({firstName: {$regex: `${authorName}`, $options: "i"}}, (err, books) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.status(200).send(books);
    });
});
```

But this is my output, which is an empty output:

[image: output]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you pls show us the full current state of your props for each component. It will help us a lot

Comment: @Alicia: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

To make part of the URL path a parameter you should define it like this

```
<Route path='/authors/:authorName' component={FilterBooks}/>
```

Then you can access it inside your component

```
this.props.match.params.authorName
```

Comment: This is not working for some reason. When i set `path='/authors/:authorName'` my url looks like `http://localhost:3000/authors/:authorName`

Comment: have you tried it? because from what I can see even if it's not working, there no way the URL will be like that!

Comment: Remember I am doing this inside another component which has been called by another component. Anything should be done differently for this kind of scenario?

Comment: Can you try to remove `<Router></Router>`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I am searching a wrong column in my DB